# Product of nonzero ideals in a connected ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, connectedness

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $I, J \trianglelefteq R$ be ideals of $R$. Assume $\{0\} \notin \{I, J\}$. I had concluded, naively, that then

$$ \neg (\forall (i,j) ∈ I \times J)(i·j = 0).
$$

However, $R$ need not be an integral domain, so this is not immediately guaranteed. 
I really *do* want to claim this, and I've left one property umentioned: $R$ is *connected* (i.e. $X^2-X ∈ R[X]$ has exactly two roots). I've already shown this to be equivalent to $R$ being nonzero *and* not isomorphic to any product of nonzero rings: $R \ncong R_1 \times R_2$.

I first had the idea that if I assumed that *all* products $i · j$ were zero, that would lead me to the contradiction that *a subring of $R$* would be isomorphic to the product of $I$ and $J$. Then I realised that $I$, $J$ are only subrings if they contain a multiplicative identity, i.e. if they equal $R$...   -.-

Can I claim the thing I want? Or is it simply untrue? And if so: why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is wrong if the ring is not an integral domain. Indeed, there are nonzero $a,b \in R$ with null product. Take $I=aR$, $J=bR$.

Comment: I see. Connectedness does not save the day? If not, I should tell you more. In my case, we have $IJ = \{0\}$ and $I+J=R$. What I need to prove is that $\{I,J\} = \{\{0\}, R\}$. The thing in the OP was my last strategy ... :'(

Comment: Take $i \in I$, $j \in J$ with $i+j=1$ (possible since $I+J=R$). Then $j=1-i$ so $i(1-i)=0$ and ...